# How to highlight a div or make a div active when clicked

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have several divs and if a div is clicked, i want to hightlight the div by changing the background-color of the div as well as the text in the div(i.e. make it active). I have done this before using JQuery by defining a class in my css and dynamically removing and adding the class. How can this be accomplished in Angular2. From researching and i shouldn't be manipulating the DOM as this is a no no in angular2. I have looked online for several examples but no success. Please

Comment: Obligatory "just use VanillaJS" comment.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make an attribute directive. Fortunately for you, Angular has [a guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) for doing almost exactly what you are looking for but with hover events. To respond to clicks instead, for the 'Respond to user action' section...

... replace this:

```
@HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    /* . . . */
}
@HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    /* . . . */
}
```

with this:

```
@HostListener('click') onMouseClick() {
    /* . . . */
}
```

To acheive a result where clicking a div that is already highlighted will unhighlight it, the full directive code would be:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  private _defaultColor = 'red';
  private el: HTMLElement;
  private highlighted: boolean = false;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) { this.el = el.nativeElement; }

  @Input('myHighlight') highlightColor: string;

  @HostListener('click') onMouseClick() {
    this.highlighted ? this.highlight('') : this.highlight(this.highlightColor || this._defaultColor);
  }

  private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

To use the directive, you apply it to an element like so:

```
<!-- With default color -->
<div [myHighlight]>Click to highlight me!</div>
<!-- With custom color -->
<div [myHighlight]="yellow">I'm a div, la di da.</div>
```

Comment: but if i click another div, the previous div won't be unhighlighted right

Comment: but if u select another div, the previous div remains highlighted. But one div has to be highlighted not all divs.

Comment: If you only want one div to be highlighted at a time, you can do the highlighting in the component that contains the highlightable divs or you can create a service that all of instances of the attribute directives (which are otherwise isolated) communicate with in order to coordinate themselves with each other.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip will keep researching on it. I'm very new to angular2 and/or angular 1. jquery has an easier approach to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Angular 2 is specifically meant to be as isolated from the DOM as possible, but even then, it's not that difficult to manipulate it when you get used to how Angular works. It may not be as convenient as jQuery to have total access to the entire DOM at all times, but ultimately, it actually helps to mitigate problems with complexity, *especially* with larger applications. There's a steeper learning curve, but I promise, it's worth it!

Comment: you suggested this can be done in the host component that contains the highlightable. How can this be achieved? Sorry for the late comment

Comment: @GunterZochbaeur's answer will show you how that'd be done. You'd have a property on the 'host' component that would keep track of which element to highlight. Each of your highlightable elements would have some sort of unique identifier that they'd check against the property on the component and apply a style or class accordingly.

Comment: thanks for being patient and as well the response. Within the same template, i can a have button that when clicked also resets the number back to 0 to have no div highlighted as well

Answer (score 0):

Just set a property depending on what item was clicked and set a class if the value matches the one of the current item. Use CSS to apply styles:

```
@Component({
  styles: [`
    div.highlight {
      background-color: red;  
    }`
  ],
  template: `
    <div (click)="highlighted = 1" [class.highlight]="highlighted === 1">div1</div>
    <div (click)="highlighted = 2" [class.highlight]="highlighted === 2">div2</div>
    <div (click)="highlighted = 3" [class.highlight]="highlighted === 3">div3</div>
`
})
class MyComponent {
  hightlighted:number = 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response i'm very new to angular2 and still don't know what you did above. Like i mentioned above came from doing JQuery to trying to learn angular2. Doing this in JQuery involves adding and removing a class but in angular2 its very different and trying to grasp the concept. But how would dynamically add and remove a class like in JQuery without manipulating the dom.

Comment: i just want when a div is clicked it's highlighted letting the user know the active div. If another div is clicked, it's highlighted and previous div is not

Comment: My code above is adding/removing the class `highlight` dynamically. Or do you mean something else with "dynamically"? You can also use `[ngClass]="someClass"` where `someClass` is a string or array with classes to add.

Comment: whats the purpose of assigning numbers

Comment: You can assign any value. The purpose is that when the current number matches the comparison, then the class will be added, otherwise removed.